# Wpf right click menu on datagrid Column

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have this datagrid( See picture )[image] And i really like to have an right click menu on a specific Column, see the red square. but it should only be that cell that has the menu. I have searched the web, but i can only find there it's the header not the column.

This is the cell code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{wpfTx:Translate Action}" Binding="{Binding Action}" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*">
                      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the style so a trigger adds the context menu. Something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Action}" Value="Whatever">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Cut" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="true" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Action}" Value="Whatever">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="EditingCut" />
                            <MenuItem Header="EditingCopy" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: No, they didn't mean that... the question author *clearly* said *it should only be that cell that has the menu*.

Comment: Doesn't the second part of my answer cover that? I removed the first part of my answer.

Comment: Ooops sorry, that's my bad, I completely missed the second part.